# Accessing the children of a node using a query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database structure on firebase Realtime database:

[image]

I am trying to access the data under the last uploaded session, which in this case is **Session9** and access the sensor readings taken at a specific time.

I have queried the database to give me the last node under **data** and added a **ListenerForSingleValueEvent**, at this location i am getting a key in **keys** List as **session9** (only one item) through the following:

```
Query lastSession = dbref.child("data").limitToLast(1);
 lastSession.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                Reading reading = node.getValue(Reading.class);
                readings.add(reading);
                textView.append(reading.getTemperature());
            } 
        }
   }
```

appending the temperature throws this error:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
```

readings is an arraylist of Reading class 
keys is a list of Strings for storing the keys for example "00:00:06"

I am making some mistake and cannot access the data that i want to add to readings list.

```
public class Reading {

private String Date;
private String Time;
private String Humidity;
private String Temperature;
private int Sound;

public Reading(){

}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: updating my question

Comment: @PeterHaddad i am getting null pointer exception while appending values to textview

Comment: Have you check if temperature is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastSession = dbref.child("data").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);

lastSession.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        for (DataSnapshot ds : keyNode.getChildren()){
            keys.add(ds.getKey());
            Reading reading = ds.getValue(Reading.class);
            readings.add(reading);

        }
    }
```

Here your reference is at node `date` therefore, you need to add two for loops to be able to access the attributes inside the time.

Comment: add `child("data").child("Session9").limitToLast(1);`

Comment: I can't do that. The sessions are automatically created and i want to access the most recent node, in this case "Session9" so cannot specifiy the child of  "data" it will change to "Session10" next time i run the system

Comment: and also try `String temp = keyNode.child("temperature").getValue(String.class);` make sure you changed the attributes in the database to lowecase `temperature` lowercase `t`

Comment: keynode.getKey()  gives Session9

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking your codes your only getting the key or the seesion but not the chidlrens

Well maybe this can help you creating second query to access the last node children

```
Query lastSession = dbref.child("data").limitToLast(1);
lastSession.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String lastItem = keyNode.getKey();
            //second query
            Query secondQuery= dbref.child("data").child(lastItem);
            secondQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

              String temp = snap.child("Temperature").getValue(String.class);

              //or you can do this

              Reading reads = snap.getValue(Reading.class);
              String temp2 = reads.getTemperature();

              textView.setText(temp);
             } 
             }
            });
        } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from that the properties of your Reading class are not publicly accessible to get/set their values.

When you call `DataSnapshot.getValue(YourClass.class)` or `DatabaseReference.setValue(instanceOfYourClass)`, the class `YourClass` must have the following:

- A public constructor that takes no arguments.
- (For getting values) Publicly accessible setters for each property
- (For writing values) Publicly accessible getters for each property

The `getValue(YourClass.class)` function will silently ignore when it fails to set an appropriate property on the target instance of that class.

So to make your `Reading` class compliant, you would define it using:

```java
public class Reading {
  public String Date;
  public String Time;
  public String Humidity;
  public String Temperature;
  public int Sound;

  public Reading(){

  }
}
```

To fix a potential typo:

```java
Query lastSession = dbref.child("data").limitToLast(1);

lastSession.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
            Reading reading = keyNode.getValue(Reading.class); // changed node to keyNode
            readings.add(reading);
            textView.append(reading.getTemperature());
        } 
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Read/Write Data Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)